3 authors with the same affiliations, but one of them has an additional affilation?
I am using the template below to present 3 authors (A, B, C) who have the same affiliation, but author C has an additional.
I have used the template below:

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{authblk}
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}


\begin{document}
%%%
\makeatletter
\title{FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF}
\author[1]{AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}
\author[1]{BBBB BBBBBBB}
\author[1,2]{CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC}

\affil[1]{IAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA}
\affil[2]{BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB}

Overleaf create me the following pdf:

As you see, the break line doesn't work here. How can I fix it?

The IEEE has its own style to state the authors. From the documentation:
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Michael Shell\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, 
Homer Simpson\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}, 
James Kirk\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}, 
Montgomery Scott\IEEEauthorrefmark{3} 
and Eldon Tyrell\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}School of Electrical and Computer Engineering\\
Georgia Institute of Technology, Atlanta, 
Georgia 30332--0250\\
Email: mshell@ece.gatech.edu}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}Twentieth Century Fox, Springfield, USA\\
Email: homer@thesimpsons.com}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
\IEEEauthorrefmark{3}Starfleet Academy, San Francisco, 
California 96678-2391\\
Telephone: (800) 555--1212, Fax: (888) 555--1212}
\IEEEauthorblockA{
\IEEEauthorrefmark{4}Tyrell Inc.,123 Replicant Street, Los Angeles, 
California 90210--4321}}

